# Tableau: Date format as MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm

Tags: date, calculated-field, tableau-api

My dataset includes 4 fields: Class, Professor, Start_date, End_date.

In the datasource, the start date and the end_date are in the form of MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm already.
I want to put all 4 fields as columns.

Example:

```
Class  Professor      Start_Date                      End_Date
1         A        01/02/2020 01:20 PM           01/02/2020 02:35 PM
```

Yet when I try to put the start and end date as columns, the years get in separate column from the months, etc. It looks quite simple, but I don't know why it has taken me so many hours to figure it out.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put date fields into Tableau, many times they default to the year of the field. Then you are able to expand the dates as you described to quarters, months, etc. What you want to do is click the drop down and select `Exact Date`.

[image]

This may cause the pill to turn continuous (green). If so, select the drop down again and select `Discreet`. The pill will turn blue like below and should be the exact date as you have in your example.

[image]